# Yii2 Krajee Select2 Plugin Formatting

Tags: html, css, widget, jquery-select2, yii2

I am using yii2 with bootstrap.

When replacing a regular input field with a select2 widget it "destroys" my page layout:

[image]

The html code of the region is:

```
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" style="padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Vendor:</label>

                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <?php
                                echo $form->field($model, 'vendor_id', ['template' => "{input}"])->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search for a vendor ...'],
                                    'pluginOptions' => [
                                        'allowClear' => true,
                                        'minimumInputLength' => 3,
                                        'ajax' => [
                                            'url' => $url,
                                            'dataType' => 'json',
                                            'size' => Select2::SMALL,
                                            'data' => new JsExpression('function(term,page) { return {search:term}; }'),
                                            'results' => new JsExpression('function(data,page) { return {results:data.results}; }'),
                                        ],
                                        'initSelection' => new JsExpression($initScript)
                                    ],
                                ]);
                                ?>
                                <!--                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputSmall"-->
                                <!--                                           placeholder="please enter vendor">-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Vendor PO
                                Number:</label>

                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputSmall"
                                       placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Vendor Inv. No:</label>

                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputSmall" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Vendor Inv.
                                Date:</label>

                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputSmall"
                                       placeholder="12/18/2014">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How can i change the styles on the select2 so that it fits again in my layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem (not with Select2, but with another Krajee-widget).
What fixed it for me was to put each line in

```
<div class="row">
    Label
    Input
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the latest version of the [Select2 plugin](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) and update.

Also you seem to be using a horizontal bootstrap form layout probably with ActiveForm. The bootstrap styling is optimized for use with `kartik\widgets\ActiveForm` which you want to [check as seen here for complex layouts](http://demos.krajee.com/active-form-demo).